# Trouble with minimal example Python Module Imports

Tags: python, import, module, package

I've made a minimal example project to attempt to resolve my module imports issue. The structure is as follows:

```
MyProject/
├── main.py
└── utils/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── foo.py
    └── bar.py
```

**main.py** only contains this code: `from utils import foo`

**__init__.py** does not contain any code

**foo.py** only contains this code: `from bar import Bar`

**bar.py** only contains this code: `class Bar: pass`

If I run `python utils/bar.py`, it runs with no exceptions.

Similarly, if I run `python utils/foo.py`, it runs with no exceptions.

However, if I run `python main.py`, it results in the following exception: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'`

Is there any way to resolve this issue? Or is it even an issue, perhaps I'm doing something I'm not supposed to?

Comment: `from .bar import Bar` ?

Comment: That fixed the ability to run main.py, but if I try to run foo.py, I get a new error: 

"ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Comment: ```
try:
    from .bar import Bar
except ImportError: # python3
    from bar import Bar
except ValueError: # python2
    from bar import Bar
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Interesting though... is that standard practice for this sort of thing?

Comment: Calling "subpackage" and "mainpackage" is not really a standard practice, neither. There may be other maybe cleaner ways avoiding these except, by tweaking python modules search path in main.py for example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the link, lots to unpack there. 

I've always called my submodules for unit testing purposes, for example in foo.py I might have an ```if __name__ == "__main__": run_tests()``` but it seems like this behavior may not be the "correct" or "intended" way of doings things after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use it as a standalone call (`python utils/foo.py`) and from main (`python main.py`), you can use both imports :

```py
try:
    from .bar import Bar
except ImportError: # for python3
    from bar import Bar
except ValueError: # for python2
    from bar import Bar
```